# Optmodel create data with 2 key-columns Optmodel

Tags: sas

I have a vector X which from 3 sets [Origin, Destination, Product] has a value, and i want to create a table that has as key columns Origin and destination and then for every product a column saying how much to transport.

So something like:

Origin Dest. ProductA ProductB...

A.........AB.......10......0

A.........AC.......5.......4

I'm trying something like this, in optmodel:

```
create data Ctrl3.Transport
    from  [Origin Destination] = {FAB, CITIES}
    {k in PRODUCT} <col('Product_'||k) = X[Origin, Destination, k]>; run;
```

But sas doesn't seem to like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TLDR;

the fix is to use `{fi in FAB, ci in CITIES}` instead of `{FAB,CITIES}`.
Then use `fi` and `ci` instead of `Origin` and `Destination`. 
The comments in the code below explain further. More details after the code.

## Code Example

```c
proc optmodel;
    set FAB                   init /RDU/;
    set CITIES                init /BCN MEL/;
    set PRODUCT               init /Planes Trains Automobiles/;
    num x{FAB,CITIES,PRODUCT} init [ /* BCN */ 3 4 5   /* MEL */ 6 7 8];
    put x[*]=; /* just to verify the declarations */

    /* This is the most efficient solution. 
       In the columns, you use fi and ci, not Origin and Destination */
    create data work.transport
        from  [Origin Destination] = {fi in FAB, ci in CITIES}
        {k in PRODUCT} <col('Product_'||k) = X[fi, ci, k]>
    ;
    /* This works because the key-set is a set expression, which confusingly,
       is not the same as an index set expression.
       The difference is important: this version creates a redundant set
       of arity 2. */
    create data work.works_but_is_inneficient
        from  [Origin Destination] = ({FAB, CITIES})
        {k in PRODUCT} <col('Product_'||k) = X[Origin, Destination, k]>
    ;    
    /* This is the original approach. 
       It fails because when the key-set is a index set expression,
       OPTMODEL looks there for dummy parameters. 
    create data work.op
        from  [Origin Destination] = {FAB, CITIES}
        {k in PRODUCT} <col('Product_'||k) = X[Origin, Destination, k]>
    ; */   
quit;
```

## Details

For efficiency, OPTMODEL has two similar types of expressions that sometimes confuse even advanced users:

- **set expression**, which evaluates some code and returns a set
- **index set expression**, which returns a set of expressions.

You can associate dummy variables with an *index set expression*. 
In the *create data* statement, when OPTMODEL sees an index set expression,
it uses those dummy variables instead of the names in the square brackets.
Since in the OP there were no such dummy variables, you get an error.